# vb.net auto-selecting drop-down list with given text from database fails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, stored-procedures

I have a drop-down list with Items of Rejection, Waiver, and Rework. And a text box of OrderNum. For the Add form, the user can select the item and insert the information to an SQL table. For the Update form, the user can look up the info by typing the OrderNum. And I want the drop-down list to auto-select the item that correspond to the data inside the table. For Example, an OrderNum of 003 has info of Rejection stored in an SQL table, then when I look up the info of 003, I would like to see the drop-down list is already staying on the item of Rejection.

The code I am using to extract data from an SQL table:

```
'Connect to defect information table(added through Add page) and fetch the according item info
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spSelectRejectionData_YH")
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=H78SQLWA01-SREP\MFGPRD;Initial Catalog=SAProcessDev;Integrated Security=True")
cmd.Connection = connection
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
connection.Open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNum", Txt_OrderNum.Text)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

'display the info with GridView
GridView_ReturnedRejectionData.DataSource = reader
GridView_ReturnedRejectionData.DataBind()
```

The code I am using to auto-select the drop-down list:

```
DropDownList_EventType.SelectedIndex = DropDownList_EventType.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList_EventType.Items.FindByText(GridView_ReturnedRejectionData.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text))
```

But it doesn't work!

If I do something like:

```
Label1.Text = GridView_ReturnedRejectionData.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text
```

then the displayed text of label will actually change to the corresponding text.

And if I do:

```
DropDownList_EventType.SelectedIndex = DropDownList_EventType.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList_EventType.Items.FindByText("Rejection")
```

then it works, too.

Why doesn't my code to auto-select the drop-down list item work?

Comment: ie, you need to set the combobox's selected item as `Rejection`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is a dropdownbox, and I want it to be set as Rejection automatically when it is rejection returned by sql table